# Tools/Solutions :Remote push notifications iOS for users

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apn

I've got a database who store the device Token, country Code and language of my users and I need to send remote notifications for all the user.
What kind of tool can I used to send all notifications by country with a batch?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what exactly you are trying to achieve but here are options based on my guess, ordered by relevance:

---

In terms of notifications you can use:

[Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

- your server controls when notification is happening
- works for all app states (open/background/closed)
- when app is closed user must accept notification to open app
- will bother user with system notifications
- **does not guaranty delivery**
- requires extra work on server-side and generation of certificates by hand

Local notifications ([some relevant info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html))

- your app controls when notification is happening
- works for all app states (open/background/closed)
- when app is closed user must accept notification to open app
- will bother user with system notifications

---

If you want updates to be invisible to user and just update app you should employ NSURLSession and NSURLConnection and work up from there. These might be of interest:

Polling updates on behalf of app with background fetches

- your app controls when update is happening (if iOS doesn't mind)
- doesn't work when app is closed
- invisible to user
- should be optimized for battery life

Keeping connection open (search "ios SocketRocket" for example implementation)

- your app totally controls updates
- won't work when app is closed
- **drains battary like crazy** (so not recommended)

---

And then there is oportunity to missuse Voice push API in a interesting way

Comment: how to deliver the message to million user with APN ? there is a tool who can do this ? i've got all the device token of user stored in database thanks

Comment: There are a series of tools which should be used. Here is nice [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial).

Comment: I would appreciate comments on downvote

Comment: THANKS for the response gp-v